# I see a constraint in my table thats not in INFORMATION SCHEMA?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, constraint

When I expand the database "Constraints" object, I see 2 of them named `DF_DocumentD_Docum_3F466844` and `df_documentdistqty`, but when I select to view everything from the "Information Schema.TABLE Constraints", the constraints named above dont show up, any idea why? 
I scripted out these constraint and it has the following info:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDistribution] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DocumentDistDate]
GO
```

and the other has:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[df_documentdistqty]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentDistribution] DROP CONSTRAINT [df_documentdistqty]
END
```

Comment: Stop using INFORMATION_SCHEMA. For anything. Seriously. https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views Also, start naming your constraints explicitly instead of taking the junk names SQL Server will supply you if you use shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Please stop using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and deprecated backward compatibility views like `sysobjects`. This is just another in the long list of things that `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is missing in order to provide a complete picture of your metadata. See this post for a more exhaustive list:

- [The case against INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views)

To find the name of the default constraints for any table, use [the catalog view `sys.default_constraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-default-constraints-transact-sql):

```
SELECT [constraint] = df.name, [column] = c.name, df.[definition]
  FROM sys.default_constraints AS df
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
    ON df.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    AND df.parent_column_id = c.column_id
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE s.name = N'dbo'
  AND t.name = N'DocumentDistribution';
```